# Google Analytics avg. page load time is always reported as 0.00 for Safari

Tags: safari, google-analytics

Has anyone had the same problem that page load time of Safari (and Safari only of the major browsers) results in 0.00 all the time?

Looks like data for Safari is not registered, both desktop and in-app.
This while Safari is the most used browser for the website.

Any solutions?

I'm using the Google Analytics script you can find on the Google Analytics site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1205784?hl=en):

> Site speed tracking occurs only for visits from those browsers that support the HTML5 Navigation Timing interface or have the Google Toolbar installed. Typically this includes: Chrome, Firefox 7 and above, Internet Explorer 9 and above, Android 4.0 browser and above, as well as earlier versions of Internet Explorer with the Google Toolbar installed.

Safari and opera don't support Navigation Timing (yet).

Comment: Opera based on Chrome will produce the numbers but Safari is the biggest gap.